# How do i setup a unittest method that checks a method inside method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have been practicing my code testing skills with unittest, and one of the holes I found in my knowledge is how to test a method, that calls other method inside of it, that requires attributes. 
For example:

```
def calc_balance(usr_input)
    new_balance = total_income() - usr_input 
    return new_balance

def total_income(value): 
    return value
```

I want to test with unittest, for example: if usr_input = 100, and my total_income() method returns 50, the test will pass if new_balance will be equal to 50.

I know how to write a test for calc_balance() that assigns usr_inputs value (that's easy), but i don't know how to pass a value to total_income() (in the unittest method I'm about to write)

I'll be glad if someone could help me with that... i couldn't any usful info... I assume that maybe I need to use the seUp() method or something like that...

***EDIT:***

```
# main.py
def calc_balance(value):
    balance = calc_income() - calc_expance() + value
    return balance

def calc_income(list_of_incomes):
    return float(sum(list(list_of_incomes)))

def calc_expance(list_of_expances):
    return float(sum(list(list_of_expances)))

# test.py

import unittest

import main

class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_calc_income(self):
        self.assertEqual(main.calc_income([1,2]), 3)

    def test_calc_expance(self):
        self.assertEqual(main.calc_expance([0,0]), 0)

    def test_calc_balance():
    self.assertEqual(main.calc_balance(1), 4)
```

As you can see, I want test_calc_balance() to pass different values to calc_balance() and test the functionality of calc_balance()...

Comment: Your example will fail the tests because it throws an error; you *don't* provide the argument total_income needs. That makes it very unclear what you're actually trying to ask.

Comment: For the test to pass successfully, I need to provide a value to total_income(). I don't know how to pass this value in my test_calc_balance() method... I'm trying to use assertEqual() inside test_calc_balance()

Comment: But providing that value is **nothing to do with the test code**. That's something that the code under test needs to do. It's totally unclear what value you're expecting it to pass or where it should come from. Please give a more illustrative example.

Comment: I've edited the post, I hope it's a little bit clearer now

Comment: Not at all. The code under test is still obviously broken so will fail the tests. To fix that you need to change *the code under test*, not the tests.

Comment: My question is how to change it under test_calc_balance() to do what I'm expecting it to do. maybe the answer is that is impossible...

Comment: You don't, you can't, you shouldn't. If the tests make broken code appear to work correctly, **what is the point of tests?!** I mean, just *think* about it.

Comment: My point is, that if I wish to achieve test coverage of 100% of my code, I have to test the calc_balance() method to. This method uses two other methods to return some output... How can I test calc_balance() to get expected value?

Comment: You can't. Because it won't return the expected value. Because it's broken. To get the right answer, `calc_balance` also needs the `list_of_incomes` and `list_of_expances` [sic] to pass to the other functions. It literally cannot work as written, and looking at the test case this should be obvious because it clearly doesn't contain enough information to expect that it would.

Comment: Thank you for the patience and the answers! I see now that I have to provide values to the calc_balance functions as variables, and I can't pass values to the functions inside the calc_balance function. I thought that there is a way to do that. Thanks again!